# Is it possible to transfer ownership of Frontier Outposts in Stellaris using console commands?

Tags: stellaris

And AI settled a really iritating Frontier Outpost in territory I was about to take. I don't want to go to war with them because they outmatch me in fleet strength but I want that system. Is there a command to transfer ownership of FO's using console commands? I tried using `own <FO id> paint` but it said that was an invalid planet ID.

Comment: I had a quick look at the wiki page: https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Console_commands but I didn't find something useful yet. However, the list is very long, I might have missed it. The `own` command should be used to take ownership of a planet.

Comment: I think you can select and destroy a destroyable structure with console commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a command to transfer ownership of the station, but you can easily destroy it with the console.

Select the FO, open the console, and use `damage 10000` to deal 10,000 damage to the FO.  You can use any number you'd like if that's not enough damage, or run the command a few times.

Comment: I'm accepting this for now. I hope in the future they actually add a command for it.

Comment: The upcoming Cherryh update plans to completely overhaul how territory is claimed, stations, and outposts, so it's quite possible.